# Let $U$ and $V$ be two $n\times n$ unitary matrices such that $UV=\lambda VU$.Then prove that $\lambda^n=1$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ and $V$ be two $n\times n$ unitary matrices such that $UV=\lambda VU$.Then prove that $\lambda^n=1$

Totally stuck on it.Can I get some help?

Comment: Hint: Look at the eigenvalues.

Comment: did not understand.will you explain please.

Answer (score 6):

Unitary is not needed, just non-singular. Eigenvalues are not needed either. Just use the multi-linearity and multiplicativity of the determinant:
$$
  \det(UV)=
  \det(\lambda VU)=\lambda^n\det(VU)=\lambda^n\det(V)\det(U)=\lambda^n\det(UV)
$$
so $\lambda^n=1$ since $\det(UV)\neq0$.

Comment: +1. Obviously non-singularity is enough. Funny, how I immediately think of the spectrum when I see 'unitary'.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The determinant is invariant under base change, so how does the determinant of $U$, say, relate to its eigenvalues? Moreover the determinant is multiplicative, so what is $\det(UV)$, what is $\det(\lambda VU)$?

Edit: I just realised that the fact that they are unitary is a red hering of sorts. Multiplicativity of the determinant and non-singularity suffice.